# C# sending data using JWT in MVC when private key is from a pfx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt

This is my first implementation of using JWT in MVC.  I have created the following token in my controller to pass to the front end when they hit my endpoint . I have used the tool on JWT.io but I am uncertain if it's worked and what I put in the signature section 'secret'. It says invalid token signature but I can see the payload.  Here is the code:

Any help or pointing in the right direction to see how it works would be great.

```
var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
     { "id", "example123" },
     { "Name", "John Doe" }
};

X509Certificate2 certX509 = new X509Certificate2(pfxFile, password);

byte[] privateKey = certX509.Export(X509ContentType.Cert, password);

string token = Jose.JWT.Encode(payload, privateKey, JwsAlgorithm.HS256);

//string[] getSecret = token.Split(".".ToCharArray());
//secret = getSecret[2];

return token;
```

The result, which seems to look like a JWT token:

eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImV4YW1wbGUxMjMiLCJOYW1lIjoiSm9obiBEb2UifQ.j4Ub0iWU-6xTbc3pvwfBy0v0o-Y2Ds6C5_ez3NIRnIk

but it doesn't validate on https://jwt.io/. Thank you in advance :)

Edit

After playing around more I found if I create a string then convert it to a byte array then use the text in the signature box it **verifies!!**.  Because my current byte array is populated from a pfx, the value to enter is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

Put private key on secret textbox. correct secret validate token.
[see snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVWHT.png)

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based on the token above what would be the actual value of the private key? I don't know what to put in that box. I've tried copy last part of token but is doesn't work.

Comment: your token looks valid. a jwt token consist 3 parts header, payload and signature. all are present in your token.

Comment: thank you yes, I am aware of this I just don't understand how to get the secret to verify signature?